# Sentencia SQL que devuelve ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis

Tags: sql, oracle

Tengo el siguiente código en Oracle SQL en la declaración de esta tabla de alumnos:

```
CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS (

ID_ALUMNO NUMBER(8,0) PRIMARY KEY,

SALUDO VARCHAR2(5),

NOMBRE VARCHAR2(25),

APELLIDO VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,

DIRECCION VARCHAR2(50),

CODPOS VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,

TELEFONO VARCHAR2(2),

EMPLEADOR VARCHAR2(50),

DIA_REGISTRO DATE NOT NULL,

CREADO_POR VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,

DIA_CREACION DATE NOT NULL,

MODIFICADO_POR VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,

DIA_MODIFICACION DATE NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY CODPOS REFERENCES CODIGO_POSTAL

);
```

Al ejecutar, da el error ORA-00906: missing left parenthesis.
Necesito localizar el error y que la query se ejecute correctamente.

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! No le faltan parentesis a los nombres de los campos en foreign key? ademas de la tabla a la que referencia? si sacas esa linea funciona? si es asi, solo estas escribiendo mal la consutla

Answer (score 1):

La llave foránea es el problema.

```
CREATE TABLE table_name
(
  column1 datatype null/not null,
  column2 datatype null/not null,
  ...

  CONSTRAINT fk_column
    FOREIGN KEY (column1, column2, ... column_n)
    REFERENCES parent_table (column1, column2, ... column_n)
);

        CREATE TABLE ALUMNOS (
        ID_ALUMNO NUMBER(8,0) PRIMARY KEY,
        SALUDO VARCHAR2(5),
        NOMBRE VARCHAR2(25),
        APELLIDO VARCHAR2(25) NOT NULL,
        DIRECCION VARCHAR2(50),
        CODPOS VARCHAR2(5) NOT NULL,
        TELEFONO VARCHAR2(2),
        EMPLEADOR VARCHAR2(50),
        DIA_REGISTRO DATE NOT NULL,
        CREADO_POR VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        DIA_CREACION DATE NOT NULL,
        MODIFICADO_POR VARCHAR2(30) NOT NULL,
        DIA_MODIFICACION DATE NOT NULL,
        CONSTRAINT FK_POSTAL
        FOREIGN KEY (CODPOS) REFERENCES CODIGO_POSTAL
        );
```